# Inserting NOW() value in datetime datatype is returning 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had a database that had a perfectly working NOW() function, displaying the right date.
And after accidentally deleted it, I created a similar database, but when I inserted NOW() to insert
current the current date, it would insert as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

The warning that showed was data was truncated at 'blog_date'. Now I don't know how to solve this problem of acquiring current time using NOW(). Below is my blog_details table, the insert command, and the error:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_details` ( `blog_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`title` char(200)  NOT NULL,  `blog_content` varchar(2500)  NOTNULL, 
`blog_date` datetime  NOT NULL,  `cat_name` varchar(30)  NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `blog_details` (`title`, `blog_content`, `blog_date`, `cat_name`)
VALUES('Breaking Bad TV Series', 'Best series evar', 'NOW()', 'Uncategorized');
```

> +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
>   | Level   | Code | Message                                        |
>   +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
>   | Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'blog_date' at row 1 |
>   +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'NOW()'` else you will pass the *string* `"NOW()"` not the function.

Comment: Really should be using UTF-8 here instead of `latin1`.

Comment: One problem is that "Breaking Bad" was not the "Best series evar". MySQL obviously knows that honor belongs to "Battlestar Galactica". (smiley face grin).  (Seriously though, you've got NOW() enclosed in single quotes, making a string literal. Remove the single quotes, it will work.)

Comment: @tadman may I know why I should use UTF-8? I have no idea how charset works(copied only from phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're inserting is the string `"NOW()"` which is completely different from the function call `NOW()`.

As `"NOW()"` is not a valid date, it goes in as zero.

Removing the quotes from that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have quotes around the `NOW()` function.  Change it to:

```
INSERT INTO `blog_details` (`title`, `blog_content`, `blog_date`, `cat_name`)
VALUES('Breaking Bad TV Series', 'Best series evar', NOW(), 'Uncategorized');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to quote the NOW() function, so try without the ' ' and see if that helps.

```
INSERT INTO blog_details(title, blog_content, blog_date, cat_name)
VALUES('Breaking Bad TV Series', 'Best series evar', NOW(), 'Uncategorized');
```